# "break-inside: avoid-column" doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm creating columns in my footer. It works well for Chrome and IE using:

```
column-count: 4;
break-inside: avoid-column;
```

I'm getting troubles with Firefox, where the property is crossed out:

[image: crossed out]

What can I do?

Using `page-break-inside: avoid`, I get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY8IT.png).
Some items move over his position, like "Item 9".

How it looks in Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

For example:

```css
#columnasFooter{
  column-count: 3;
}
#columnasFooter li{
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul id="columnasFooter">
    <li>Title column 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title column 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
            <li>Item 9</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title column 3
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 14):

I tried bugfix with `page-break-inside: avoid`, but for me it didn't work fine with only this property and value on Firefox.

Then I used the following solution and, in my case, work well for Firefox, Chrome and Edge:

```
#columnasFooter {
  column-count: 3;
}

#columnasFooter li {
  /* for Chrome and Edge */
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  /* for Firefox */
  display: inline-grid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

/* for Chrome and Edge */
@supports (break-inside: avoid-column) {
  #columnasFooter li  {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I used [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) rule to bugfix. Maybe, it could be useful to someone

Answer (score 8):

Works properly in Firefox with `overflow: hidden` but this doesn't work in Chrome. So we should use `@support` query to control overflowing. The below code works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

```css
#columnasFooter {
  column-count: 3;
}

#columnasFooter li {
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  overflow: hidden; /* fix for firefox */
}

@supports (break-inside: avoid-column) {
  #columnasFooter li {
    overflow: visible; /* for chrome */
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="columnasFooter">
  <li>Title column 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Title column 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Title column 3
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Fire fox does not have support to `break-inside` see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside 
**SO**
**Use `page-break-inside:` for firefox:**

```
column-count: 4;
break-inside: avoid-column;
page-break-inside:avoid;
```

See here about `page-break-inside:avoid;` :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside

Comment: Using page-break-inside, in Firefox, It shows me four columns, but some items that they are in 'li' item, are moved into another column.
I attached a picture in the OP.

Comment: attach image how it looks in chrome please

Answer (score 2):

Just applying `overflow: hidden` on the li alongside  `breakInside: "avoid"`, fixed the issue for me on Firefox and it continued to work on Chrome

Answer (score 1):

With the release of [Firefox version 92.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/92), the `avoid-column` value works for `break-inside` (Firefox added support for `avoid-page` as well):

```css
#columnasFooter{
    column-count: 3;
}
#columnasFooter li{
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<ul id="columnasFooter">
    <li>Title column 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title column 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
            <li>Item 9</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title column 3
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There must have been a regression as Item 9 is appearing in the 3rd column for me as of Firefox 101.0.1

Comment: @EoghanM Shows up in column 2 for me in Firefox 118; don't think I ever checked v101, so if it was a regression, it was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

try this i think its work

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

Comment: Doesn't work correctly. Now I get some items move over his position.